# Salesforce API C# Whitelist Server Proxy Authentication Required Login Issue

Tags: api, c#, login

I was wondering if someone can help me with a login issue I am having with my .NET application. I have whitelisted the server with salesforce IPs through my company but I am still getting a (407) proxy authentication required error when trying to log on. The code below is very straightforward and if I set up the proxy in the code it works fine. I am using the plain password without the security token. Am I missing something?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = "<username>";
        string password = "<password>";

        SforceService binding = new SforceService();

        binding.Timeout = 60000;

        LoginResult lr;

        lr = binding.login(username, password);

        String authEndPoint = binding.Url;

        binding.Url = lr.serverUrl;

        binding.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader();
        binding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = lr.sessionId;
    }
```

Comment: 407 is for HTTP Proxy auth, so will be related to your local network setup, nothing to do with the actual request to sfdc.